# ¿Por qué se dice verde "botella"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, adjetivos

Me he encontrado la frase siguiente:

> Un gran coche verde botella nos esperaba delante de la puerta del Gobierno Civil.

Sin "botella" la frase se comprende bien. ¿Qué aporta, entonces, la botella?

Comment: ¿Dónde encontraste esta frase?, por favor, [edit] tu pregunta con esta información.

Comment: Como dice Ra_ , tiene un origen antiguo. Pero aparte en España(y casi todo el mundo) se conoce "verde botella" al característico color del vidrio de las botellas de vino.

Comment: En Inglés, la frase es _[bottle-green](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bottle_green)_.  Quizás, es [un calco](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calco_sem%C3%A1ntico).

Comment: Es para especificar el tono del color, como amarillo canario, rojo carmesí, azul marino, azul cielo... etcétera.

Comment: Sin "botella" la frase no se comprende tan bien... Un coche verde claro, o verde "fosforito", puede ser de cualquier cosa. Un coche verde "botella" muy probablemente sea militar o, si es en España, de la Guardia Civil, con lo cual el especificar el tono ayuda a dar más información en la frase.

Answer (score 19):

Actualmente hay botellas de cualquier color, sin embargo, hace unas décadas las botellas de vidrio eran mayoritariamente de color verde o transparentes (al menos en España). Verde botella se usa para referirse al tono de verde de aquellas botellas de vidrio.

Fuente: [Coloración del vidrio. Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloraci%C3%B3n_del_vidrio)

> Cuando el vidrio aparece en occidente, en el imperio romano, el vidrio
>   tenía una coloración verde oscura, con la cual se emparenta su nombre.
>   Verde oscuro en latín se dice *viride* o *viridus*, con lo cual se
>   bautizó al vidrio como tal.
>
> ...

[image]

Comment: Color del vidrio verde romano:
http://www.artehistoria.com/v2/jpg/HIC18095.jpg